# Why OR (||) statement doesn't work in while loop, javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I wrote a program to solve a task, but doesn't work as expected, so I started debuggin. And noticed that I have issue in my while loop. So I completely commented block (you can just totally ignore comment part) and incremented `leftPointer` and `rightPointer` just to test if my while loop stops properly, but indeed it does not and I have no idea why. The idea is let the loop run until both of statements, `i-leftPointer` and  `i+rightPointer` are false. If one of them is false let it still run. And as you can see in console first statement is true, second is false, but it DOES NOT go inside while loop. What is a problem?

```
var maxSubArray = function(nums) {
    let curSum = 0;
    let maxSum = 0;
    
    for(let i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++)
        {
            curSum = maxIndex(nums, i);
            if(curSum > maxSum) maxSum = curSum;
        }
    return maxSum;
};

function maxIndex(nums, i){
    console.log('New number -------------------------', i)
    let curSum = nums[i];
    let maxSum = nums[i];
    let leftPointer = 1;
    let rightPointer = 0;
    let leftTurn = true;
    let rightTurn = false;
    console.log((i - leftPointer > 0), (i + rightPointer) < nums.length)
    while(((i - leftPointer) > 0) || ((i + rightPointer) < nums.lenght))
        {
          /*  if(i - leftPointer > 0 && leftTurn === true){
                curSum += nums[i - leftPointer];
                --leftPointer;
            }
            if(i + rightPointer > 0 && rightTurn === true){
                curSum += nums[i - rightPointer];
                ++rightPointer;
            }
            if(curSum > maxSum)
                maxSum = curSum;
            leftTurn = !leftTurn;
            rightTurn = !rightTurn */ 
            ++leftPointer;
            ++rightPointer;
            console.log('leftPointer ' + (i - leftPointer))
            console.log('rightPointer ' + (i + rightPointer))
       }
    return maxSum;
}

Console log
    New number ------------------------- 0
    false true
    New number ------------------------- 1
    false true
    New number ------------------------- 2
    true true
    leftPointer 0
    rightPointer 3
    New number ------------------------- 3
    true true
```

PS here is description of a task in casee if you needed
Given an integer array nums, find the contiguous subarray (containing at least one number) which has the largest sum and return its sum.

Example:

Input: [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4],
Output: 6
Explanation: [4,-1,2,1] has the largest sum = 6.

Comment: maybe because you misspelled length...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you misspelled `length`.

Change

```
while(((i - leftPointer) > 0) || ((i + rightPointer) < nums.lenght))
```

to

```
while(((i - leftPointer) > 0) || ((i + rightPointer) < nums.length))
```

and see if that works.